# How to correctly add a list of objects to database, working with multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework

My database looks like this: [Database Diagram MSSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHD4f.png)

So every time I'm adding a fish to the database, I want to add the fish's continent, waterlagen and verbanden.

Tables Continenten, Waterlagen & Verbanden are already filled with objects from an array after creating the database.

I'm using `List<Continent> Continenten;` for example to store multiple continents.

So I tried:

```
Vis nieuweVis = new Fish();
nieuweVis.Naam = "Molly";

foreach(Continent c in Continenten)
    nieuweVis.Continenten.Add(c)
```

so in the table VisContinenten
I assume that EF will automatically fill in the FishId and ContinentId which are foreignkeys.

I want records in that table also to be unique so I add a unique key to both the columns in VisContinenten so that fish 1 on continent 1 won't appear twice in that table.

Error I get:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
> properties for their relationships
>
> Additional information: Unable to update the EntitySet 'VisContinenten' because it has a DefiningQuery and no `<InsertFunction>` element exists in the `<ModificationFunctionMapping>` element to support the current operation.

Comment: Is this code first? Looks like a typical many-to-many. Need to see the 3 models for Vissen, Verbanded and VisVerbanded.

Comment: Not code first, i first created database in SQL Management studio and then created a EF Model from database. 

When creating the model i get 3 of these warnings: 

`

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  Error 6002: The table/view 'Whataboutthisfish.dbo.VisContinenten' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view. Catattafish G:\Whataboutthisfish\Catattafish\WhataboutthisfishEDMX.edmx `

Comment: I didnt put a primary key on the 3 tables cause i want to use both foreign keys in each table as unique key

Comment: EF needs keys. The keys of the bridge table should be configured as [composite](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/04/06/database-design-many-to-many-join-tables/).

Comment: You are missing PK in your 'VisContinenten'